# Excel IF formula with specific

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that is calculating if a certain cell is greater than `0` then multiplying 2 cells together. I only want to show the result though within one cell and then after that time the following cells are to be nought. At the moment I have cells with the same amount in e.g. `Jan = £7, Feb = £7` but I need `Feb` to be `0` as `Jan` already has a `sum` in it.

```
=IF(M1>0,$F$1*$F$9,0)
```

Comment: It is not easy to follow your question like this, please share a screenshot with your data and desired output.

Comment: Perhaps show some data to help illuminate the problem. Sounds like either don't have a formula in other cells or add a test that if cell X > 0 then do stuff Else 0... bit like your existing formula really!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `AND` and `OR` commands...

```
=IF(AND(M1>0, OR(ISBLANK(janCell),janCell=0)),$F$1*$F$9, 0)
```

Note that you haven't provided a great deal of useful information there. We know nothing about the structure of your work sheet, where the month results are stored etc.  You should think about your question more before writing it up.

Hope the formula above helps.

Comment: Hi Paul - this is what I have so far - =IF(AND(M2>0,sum(J27:K27=0),$F$2*$F$10,0)

Comment: But it is not liking the sum element. Any ideas on that please.

Comment: @Amanda - And does it work? What you've typed there appears to be missing a closing bracket for the `AND`.

Comment: Yes apologies on the info I wasn't too sure how much info to put in.

Comment: @Amanda -Try: `=IF(AND(M2>0,sum(J27:K27=0)),$F$2*$F$10,0)`

Comment: No it is saying I need an opening or closing parenthesis but no idea where to put it

Comment: Thanks Paul tried that but just saying #VALUE!

Comment: @Amanda - Also, to be honest, I would avoid anchoring the cells like you have. Try: `=IF(AND(M2>0,sum(J27:K27=0)),F$2*F$10,0)` instead. Apologies - wrong way round!

Comment: @Amanda - Sorry - I can't help you with the `#VALUE!` issue - you haven't provided enough detail in your question.

Comment: @Amanda - just spotted it - you've change the `SUM(J27:K27=0)` to `SUM(J27:K27)=0`.

Comment: Great thanks Paul that has worked with changing the bracket

Comment: @Amanda - Have you taken into account about anchoring the cells? I suspect that you'd have a list of cells for Jan to Dec, and the formulas will follow suit? If so, by anchoring the values to the given cells (basically it'll always be `F2` and `F10`). It looks like you are using these ranges in columns as opposed to rows. When you auto-fill these values (by dragging the little square at the bottom right of the cell range) your formula will not copy properly to adjacent cells. Try using `F$2*F$10` instead, that way subsequent formulae will update (i.e. `G$2*G$10`, `H$2:H$10`, ... `R$2*R$10`).

Comment: Thanks again for the advice Paul.